# Liquibase in SpringBoot load changelog from different module

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I have here a multimodule project in SpringBoot.

The task is to create the DB environment based on liquibase, but the data definition is stored in another subpackage

First there is a project containing shared database code:

```
db-common
- src
-- main
--- java
---- com
----- myproject
------ dbcommon
------- dbdao
-------- ProductDAO.java
-------- CustomerDAO.java
------- db
-------- changelog
--------- changelog-master.yaml
```

Changelog-master.yaml is the file containing all data liquibase should use to create the database. Due to the project architecture db-common is just a library.

Database set up should be done from another project customerservice which uses db-common:

```
customerservice
- src
-- main
--- java
---- com
----- myproject
------ customerservice
```

In customerservice application.properties the following is defined:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:com/myproject/dbcommon/db/changelog/changelog-master.yaml
```

However, Liquibase says:

```
Liquibase failed to start because no change log could be found at classpath:com/myproject/dbcommon/db/changelog/changelog-master.yaml
```

Related dependency in pom.xml of customerservice is set properly, I can use all of those DAOs.

Any idea how to get liquibase to use changelog-master.yaml from db-common?

Comment: non Java files must be in `src/main/resources` if you don't place them there they wil be ignored by maven.

Comment: if you just want to reuse `changelog-master.yaml` in any project it might be possible to just put it in some common directory at the same level as the very base level of the project and add this directory as resource folder for any project that needs it. for maven the configuration could be found here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html